# How to get icon info of specific window in python?

Tags: python, window, icons

I'm building an auto time logger and i group the tasks by window title and process. But there are some tasks that are done in browser (chrome, firefox, etc.).
From what i understood searching the net is that it's a bit more difficult to obtain the current url. So on second thought i figured out that i just need to know the site that is opened and probably i could get this info if i know what is the icon displayed in the tab.

I'm using win32gui, psutil and win32process.

```
fWin = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
parentWindow = win32gui.GetParent(fWin)
fWinText = win32gui.GetWindowText(fWin)
if parentWindow is not 0:
    fWinText = win32gui.GetWindowText(parentWindow)
fWinPID = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(fWin)
fWinProc = psutil.Process(fWinPID[1])
```

That's the main info i'm getting. 
Also with:

```
win32ui.GetForegroundWindow()
```

I get the object of the window, but still can't find function that give me the icon info.

If anyone has ideas, will be great : )

Comment: some doubts here - By icon, do you mean favicon? If that is the case, how do you think of handling sites which dont have one ? What are you using for performing tasks in Browser? If its some automation driver, you can get the URL i guess.

Comment: Yes, i'm talking about the favicon.

Comment: It's actually about one site specifically. shotgunsoftware.com - Project management service. And i when we're working in this site i need to log this king of work.

Comment: What do you mean by automation driver? Sorry i'm not that familiar with coding in python.